# Как из php передать массив в javascript?

Tags: массивы, php, html, javascript

Есть два вопроса: 1) как из базы получить то что мне необходимо. 2)как передать, то что я получил из базы в javascript
у меня есть html файл.
в нем подключен javascript map.js и файл map.php. джава скрипт нормально выполняется, а пхп файл не выполняется вроде. как привязать джаваскрипт и пхп вместе в html файле, я не знаю. я не изучал пхп и джаваскрипт, у меня немного другая специализация, но сейчас по необходимости приходится что-то писать.

вот код map.php:

```
 <?php 
        $hostname = "***************"; 
        $username = "****************"; // имя пользователя (в Denwer`е по умолчанию "root")
        $password = "**********"; 
        $dbName = "***********";
        $table = "test_table";
        mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Не могу создать соединение");
        mysql_select_db($dbName) or die (mysql_error());
        $query = "SELECT coord1,coord2 FROM $table";
        $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_close();
?>
```

тут из базы мне нужно получить массив элементов координата 1 и координата 2 
пример формата элемента массива 
[54.345324,23.4354353]

потом этот массив нужно передать в javascript, тут он у меня уже инициализирован, но нужно его заполнять из базы. Массив называется markers.
map.js

```
var map;
var point = 1;
//точки для двигателя
var markers = {
    point1:[55.755786, 37.617633],
    point2:[55.7543712, 37.6104643],
    point3:[55.7531491, 37.6101551],
    point4:[55.7506212, 37.6101143],
    point5:[55.7541852, 37.5274149],
    point6:[55.7473746, 37.609723],
    point7:[55.803607, 37.328598],
    point8:[55.7422534, 37.6064208],
    point9:[55.7397707, 37.6055861],
    point10:[55.704945, 37.5277036],
};

$(document).ready(function(){
       //карта
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.755786, 37.617633);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    //отмечаем все точки на карте
    var marker = [];
    for(i in markers){
        marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][0], markers[i][1]), 
            map: map
        });
    }

    //map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(markers.point10[0], markers.point10[1]));

    //двигатель карты по точкам
    function mover(){
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(markers["point"+point][0], markers["point"+point][1]));
        point ++;
        if(point>10)point=1;
    }

    //карта не используется
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(){
        setTimeout(mover, 500);//время в милисекундах
    });
    });
```

P.S.
так как из-за недостатка очков нет возможности ни плюсануть, ни ответить, напишу здесь.
благодарю пользователя **Inkognitoo**,**dekameron** за помощь. У меня получилось то, что я хотел реализовать. Все работает. Воспользовался идеей decameron.первый или второй раз работаю с пхп. Я долгое время на выкупал в чем суть и почему не работает,оказывается у меня был html файл а в нем <? ?> и также <script> потом я сделал index.php и загнал html в echo, также javascript загнал в echo. и в нужное месте вставил var markers. вообщем всем спасибо за помощь и потраченное время.

НО РЕШЕНИЕ Deonisa оказалось лучше потому, что не приходится все запихивать в echo, можно использовать html страницу и будет все аккуратно и чисто. действительно это не гавнокод будет.

http://www.wiseguys.com.ua/ вот готовое решение, ну это только часть того, что я планирую, но уже хорошо что один кусок готов. я вообще не вэб разработчик, работаю с андроид ос.

Comment: использовать Json-формат.

Comment: Не мне ли кажется что не в первый раз вижу такой вопрос в этом сайте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**mysql_query();** возвращает не таблицу, а **дескриптор** результирующей таблицы. В Вашем случае - два столбца с элементами. 
Значения из дескриптора вы можете получить например, функцией [mysql_fetch_assoc();](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)
. *Массив из php в JavaScript передается через старое доброе **echo**. Почитать об этом можно* [тут](http://phpfaq.ru/na_tanke#js)

Код может выглядеть примерно так: ( набирал по памяти, могут быть ошибки )

```
$query = "SELECT coord1,coord2 FROM $table";
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

echo 'var markers = {'; 
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
  echo "point{++$i}:[{$myrow['coord1']}, {$myrow['coord2']},";
echo '};';
```

Comment: Видать, более тупого способа не нашлось, так вы решили остановиться на передаче данных в цикле. Ничего, этот вариант тоже может побороться за "перво место".

Comment: вы знаете другой способ? Не привлекающий циклы? Поделитесь?

Comment: @Inkognitoo, сударь, не нужно передергивать, я говорил про **передачу данных** в цикле. Если вы этого не поняли - соболезную. А более человеческий способ, предложил @dekameron: сформировать полный ответ и только потом отправить.

Comment: Человек ведь сразу написал: " я не изучал пхп и джаваскрипт". Я отлично помню себя и свои первые шаги. Когда я задавал вопрос - меня интересовало самое простое решение, которое я смогу понять, применить, улучшить и переделать. Прежде чем летать - учатся ходить, а то и ползать. P.S. вам, да и всем любящим кидаться словами "тупо" и "соболезную", советую к прочтению: http://habrahabr.ru/post/178747/

Comment: @Inkognitoo, Лучше вообще ничего не предлагать, чем втюхивать, пусть и простое, но решение из разряда "*учимся гомнокодить с нуля*".

Comment: Я ничего не "втюхивал", я предложил вариант, @Firespirit волен сам выбирать, брать его в расчёт или нет. Рад, что вы предложили лучше.

Answer (score 2):

*Мой ответ - это больше дополнение/комментарий к ответу [[@dekameron](/users/13096/dekameron)](/users/13096/dekameron).*

Всё бы ничего, но ни в первом ответе, ни в вашем, ничего не сказано про **[ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**. Типа, оставили ТС пищу для размышлений? ))

**PHP**

```
$data = false;
if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){
    // если хоть что-то есть, то формируем ответ
    while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $data['point'.(++$i)] = array($myrow['coord1'], $myrow['coord2']);
    }
}
echo json_encode($data); // и ничего дописывать не надо
```

**JS**

```
// отправляем запрос в map.php
$.ajax({
    url:'map.php',
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {key:val}, // если надо
    success: function(data){
        if(data){
            console.log(data); // все полученные координаты, именно в том виде, который требовался ТС
        } else {
            // действия в случае, если координаты в БД отсутствуют
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT coord1,coord2 FROM $table";
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$data = new stdClass();

while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
  $key = 'point'.(++$i);
  $data->$key = array($myrow['coord1'], $myrow['coord2']);
}

//В нужном месте:

echo 'var markers = '.json_encode($data).';';
```

**upd**

P.S. Когда же вы перестанете юзать mysql_* функции?

P.P.S. stdClass для того, чтобы при пустой $data вывело фигурные скобки, а не квадратные